# KNN on PCA data

Tags: matlab, pca, knn

I eager to find k nearest neighbors in dimensional reduced fisher iris data. So I have separately codes for PCA and kNN in Matlab:

for PCA:

```
load fisheriris
[pc,score,latent,tsquare] = princomp(meas); 
pc,latent
cumsum(latent)./sum(latent); % variance explained by each component

gscatter(score(:,1), score(:,2), species, [], [], [], 'on', 'PC1', 'PC2')
title('Projected Iris data'), grid on
```

[image]

for kNN

```
x = meas(:,3:4);
y = [5 1.45;6 2;2.75 .75]; % how do we choose query points?


[n,d]=knnsearch(x,y,'k',10);

gscatter(x(:,1),x(:,2),species)
line(y(:,1),y(:,2),'marker','x','color','k',...
   'markersize',10,'linewidth',2,'linestyle','none')

line(x(n,1),x(n,2),'color',[.5 .5 .5],'marker','o',...
   'linestyle','none','markersize',10)
set(legend,'location','best')
tabulate(species(n,:))
```

[image]
how can I show with plot kNN on PCA data?

Thank you for your support!

Comment: How to connect these two sources Please help!

Comment: This question is severely mis-written and no one has any idea what you're trying to do or what you're asking, hence why it has gone nearly a year with no response. You should really try to rewrite this using better English. If you're English isn't that good, maybe get a friend who is a native English speaker to help you formulate your thoughts and write your question.